# I have a date object, need to format it for cache lookups, simpledateformat isn't thread-safe?

Tags: java, spring, datetime, spring-mvc

In my servlet, when a request comes in, I create a date object.

```
Date now = new Date();
```

I want to perform a cache lookup, and I need to create a helper function that will format the date to:

2012.04.24-10:34

which is:  `yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm`

I had this using simple date format:

```
public class DateHelpers {
      public static final DateFormat minuteDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm", Locale.US);

      public static String getDateKey(Date now) {
         // use minuteDateFormat to format date
      }
}
```

But I was reading that simple date format isn't thread-safe.

I am not parsing a string to a dateformat, so maybe there is a better and faster way to do this?

I am taking a date object and formatting it to a string, and it must be thread safe as many requests will be using this DateHelper static method to get the key from the date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a step back, if you are really pressed for performance, I would avoid formatting the date at all and just use the unix timestamp for key (i.e. System.currentTimeMllis()). If you want to lookup based on existing date object `date.getTime()` gives you the timestamp.

If you want to round it to a minute, you can int-divide and multiply by 60,000 - it's way faster and guaranteed threadsafe.

For the cases when I format dates, I ususally either create the date format on demand (it is not *that* expensive), or I have an pool of utility objects which I explicitly associate with each worker.

The thread local solution will work, but over time it is too easy to lose track of all the TL's and you end up with code that is more difficult to debug.

Comment: Yes all I need is a per minute date representation, its for a cache key.  I think I'll go with currenttimemilli then once I wrap my head around it, thanks man!

Comment: To get a per-minute key do `(timeMillis / 60000) * 60000`. Strictly speaking, you don't need the multiplication part if you don't plan to compare it with other timestamps, but I like to keep uniform scale.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`ThreadLocal<DateFormat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

```
public class DateHelpers {
    private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> minuteDateFormat = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {
        @Override protected DateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm", Locale.US);
        }
    };

    public static String getDateKey(Date now) {
        DateFormat df = minuteDateFormat.get();
       // use df to format date
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## java.time

The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. (See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).)

Included is a new date formatter which **is thread-safe**: [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Another advantage is the support of optional parts in the formatting pattern.

Its creation will be like this:

```
protected static DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc for SimpleDateFormat:

> It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread.

Too many developers see that, and their first instinct is to synchronize on ThreadLocal or to add synchronization blocks. Before you know it, the code is riddled with ThreadLocal, often times as a "precautionary measure", but not out of necessity. It can become incredibly difficult to troubleshoot. There is no reason to synchronize your format using thread local unless there is absolutely no alternative. If you really do have a date format that will never change (why else mark it static final with a given string format), then what you really need is an instance of that date format created ONCE in the JVM. It would be better to use inversion of control to inject your simple date format when the application starts. That way when you need it anywhere, you know it exists.

Comment: Nope, sorry. You either synchronize or use a ThreadLocal certainly not both. More importantly formatting a `Date` using `SimpleDateFormat` changes the internal state of the `SimpleDateFormat`. It is absolutely not OK to to put a `SimpleDateFormat` into a `static final` field and access it from more than one thread.

Comment: You misunderstood me. The question is not whether or not ThreadLocal is the solution for making SimpleDateFormat thread safe. Obviously in this situation it is. I'm saying the question @Blankman should be asking is in this situation do you even need SimpleDateFormat to be static final (and thus thread safe). My answer would be no. The format will NEVER change. He will always be using the same format for every date key across the entire application.

Comment: No, I understood you. The format WILL change as soon as you invoke `#format`. The instance variable `calendar` will change and different methods will read it during the formatting process. So if you have two thread inside the `#format` method of the same object the result is likely going to be corrupted.

Marking stuff as `static final` does not make it immutable or thread safe. Consider having an `ArrayList` in a `static final` field. Surely you're not going to argue that the value of it will never change.

Comment: True, but that isn't what's happening here. The integrity of the date key requires that one format and locale is defined (as demonstrated by the constructor call). If you're worried about another call to format() then the issue and argument changes altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one

```
public class DateFormatTest {

  private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> df
                 = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>(){
    @Override
    protected DateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm", Locale.US);
    }
  };

  public Date convert(String source)
                     throws ParseException{
    Date d = df.get().parse(source);
    return d;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) from Joda time API. It is immutable and thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

[FastDateFormat](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html) from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) is thread-safe. In addition you don't create ClassLoader-leaks by subclassing ThreadLocal. However it does only do formatting, not parsing.

An alternative would be the excellent [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library that has stateless and therefore thread-safe parsers and formatters.